# How do I override _path helpers in rails properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model called *resource* in my rails app and in need of modifying the return value of the helper *resource_path*, I've read some docs and SO Q/A and they're generally suggesting put the customized helper in *app/helpers/application_helper.rb*. The thing bothers me is that what do I do with the old auto generated helper? should I do something like

```
undef resource_path
```

before I go ahead and write my own helper? Currently I have a *resource_path* method defined within *ApplicationHelper*, interestingly when I open rails console, app.resource_path and helper.resource_path giving me different result.

Also, I'd like to hear a deeper explanation on how *_path* helpers implemented and how they are related to *link_to* helper, as the source code are kinda hard to read with so many meta programming techniques involved

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are able to do it like following:

```
resources :photos, as: 'images'
```

in your config/routes.rb file. 
More details you can find here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html especially 4.3 Overriding the Named Helpers